# Understanding Python Numpy while performing mathematical operations

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Numpy array. And I write the following code :

```
import numpy as np
     np_mat = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]])
     np_mat * 2
     print(np_mat.shape)
     np_mat = np_mat + np.array([[10, 11],[-1,-2]])
     print(np_mat)
```

Surprisingy Python throws an error saying

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-557c7da40077> in <module>
      5 np_mat * 2
      6 print(np_mat.shape)
----> 7 np_mat = np_mat + np.array([[10, 11],[-1,-2]])
      8 print(np_mat)
      9 print(np.median(np_mat))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (2,2)
```

Again when I make a small modification to the code that is, the same snippet but just
`np_mat = np_mat + np.array([10, 11])` it runs well showing the output

```
[[11 13]
 [13 15]
 [15 17]]
```

I didn't understand the difference, how does Numpy addition work inside? Is there any rule for it? I am pretty sure that Numpy addition/multiplications don't work like normal matrix operations in algebra. Then what's the trick?

Also, for a Numpy 2D array like

```
np_mat = np.array([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4],
                   [5, 6]])
```

when I write `np.median(np_mat)` it says the result is 3.5. How is it possible that the median is a number when the array is 2D? I could see the same results when I do a multiplication : `np_mat = np_mat * np.array([10, 11])` the output comes

```
[[10 22]
 [30 44]
 [50 66]]
```

Numpy seems baffling! Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you intend to add a 4-dimensional vector to a 6-dimensional vector? cause that's what you're trying to do in your code. I'm pretty sure it's mathematically wrong.

Comment: @yann ziselman Which one is 4dimendional and which is 6-dimensional vector? Sorry but I am totally new to Python. Also I have edited my question.

Comment: 'np_mat' is a 6-dimensional vector. 'np.array([[10, 11],[-1,-2]])' is a 4 dimensional vector.

Comment: @yann ziselman But see even this one is a 2 dimensional vector `np_mat = np_mat + np.array([10, 11])`. Still it produced the output? How come?

Comment: as you can see in the documentation to which you have links in the answers below, when one of the array's dimensions has a length of one, numpy treats it like a ones vector times a scalar that you're adding to your vector.

Comment: @yannziselman They're not 4 and 6 dimensional vectors; they both have 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

[General Broadcasting Rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules)

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
> element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions
> and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> - they are equal, or
> - one of them is 1

When one of the dimensions is `1`, it will expand to the shape of the other array in the calculation.

In your first example the shapes are `(3,2)` and `(2,2)` so the right most dimension works, but the 3 and 2 are incompatible.

In the second example the shapes are `(3,2)` and `(1,2)`, so the right most dimension works and 3 is compatible with 1.

For the median example, just read the docs for what is happening:

> axis{int, sequence of int, None}, optional
> Axis or axes along which the medians are computed. The default is to compute the median along a
> flattened version of the array.

By default, the median is calculated across all of the values in the array. However, you can select an axis that you would like to compute across.

Comment: Thank you so much. So basically you meant that as the second example had a 1 it worked fine? Now what would have been the outcome had the 2 dimensions been (3,2) and (2,1)?

Comment: 3 is incompatible with 2, so this would not work.

Comment: Also here 2 too is incompatible with 1, so does this too have an effect?

Comment: what do you mean by 'flattened version of the array'?

Comment: It converts the 2D array into a 1D array. For example, do `np_mat.flatten()`.

Comment: With the shapes (3,2) and (2, 1), the 2 and 1 are compatible as it follows the second bullet point in the broadcasting rules. It can be quite confusing to understand what is going on with broadcasting, but I suggest you read the whole broadcasting website to understand - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays match in size along an axis, then elements will be operated on element-by-element, similar to how the built-in Python function zip() works. If one of the arrays has a size of 1 in an axis, then that value will be broadcast along that axis, or duplicated as many times as necessary to match the number of elements along that axis in the other array.

Please read more [here](https://realpython.com/numpy-tutorial/#broadcasting)

Comment: What is the meaning of 'If the arrays match in size along an axis'?

Comment: @QUEEN, An array size and shape are different. Try printing the shape of them. You will get it easily